# Is it possible to create superscript font with PHP GD?

Tags: php, html, image, text, gd

Is there a way to create superscript text using GD/PHP. I want to create a date format of 20th June where the "th" is superscript however I can't find a way to do this. I have tried `<sup>th</sup>` but this just displays it as it is.

Comment: GD2 has no HTML support, maybe [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is an option?; Meta-level related: [How to take screenshot of rendered HTML page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253099/how-to-take-screenshot-of-rendered-html-page)

Answer (score 2):

You may have to draw the superscript text separately.  You can detect where the original text ends by using [imageftbbox()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imageftbbox.php) and then using the result to calculate where to draw the superscript text using a smaller font size.